# script to load an external image after image name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

How to make something like this: when press on a button, a cell appear, in that cell I write the image name (without extension) and when I press OK the image is loaded from an external folder.

Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: In AS3 or AS2? What have you tried? Where is the external folder?

Comment: Give some code you have tried, and say what isn't working. If you haven't attempted this yourself yet, then you're basically asking us to write the program for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: Indeed Puggsoy, my programming knowledge are low, and when I "asked" google "script to load an external image" he lead me here, at StackOverflow, so I put the question here in hope to someone give me a  script but if you say S.O. isn't for that kind of problem can you make me a recommendation where can I find help for my little script?